# Why ASMX is platform specific in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin.forms, asmx

I see I need to implement ASMX on each platform I need to consume it: one for Android, one for IoS, one for UWP, and so on.

It reference to the same model/classes/methods, why I need to replicate it for each platorm? The WSDL is the same.

Can you give to me an example?

Comment: Unfamilar with Xamarin, but could WCF be more appropriate here?

Comment: well worth checking in your case, specially the second half of the article [Developing Cross-Platform Mobile Apps using Xamarin](http://www.codemag.com/article/1401051)

Comment: ASMX? Isn't that dead just as WCF?

Comment: ASMX is a server-side way of creating SOAP services, not something that would generally exist in the client. In its current form, your question isn't answerable.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto arguably its more dead than WCF.

Comment: @Amy yes, of course. But, for public web services, I consider WCF completely dead. ASP.NET Web API 1, 2 and now ASP.NET Core all replaced it

Comment: @markzzz You don't need to. You can implement it only in PCL.

Comment: @YuriS: can't see "add service reference" on VS2017. Can you show to me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Unload your PCL project. Open it for edit. Change it to Profile 78, save it and reload. Now you get an option to add Service Reference